# What to use instead of WebViewPage.RenderPage method in ASP.NET 5 MVC6

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Given an example based on old MVC5:
Views/Shared/Index.cshtml - a view for a SPA app. It contains some markup and a reference to a layout-page:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

In _Layout.cshtml there're number of includes which are being used via `RenderPage` helper:

```
@RenderPage("~/Views/Shared/_ImportCssInline.cshtml")
@RenderPage("~/Views/Shared/_ImportCssLinks.cshtml")
```

Now in AspNet5 `@RenderPage` helper isn't available.
It was the method of `WebViewPage`/`WebPageBase`/`WebPageRenderingBase`. Now they were replaced by `RazorPage`. But there's no `RenderPage` method in it.

What should be used instead?

p.s. [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/2412)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've always had success using `@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_ImportCssInline.cshtml")` rather than `@RenderPage` - I hope there's not usage differences for you.  There are also async versions of these imports now, too.

Since the `Html` property is now injectable as the interface `IHtmlHelper`, I assume the direct methods were removed in the improvements for the testability of the views.