# Include a html before another html page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

[image]

I google a lot and find many solutions, but none of them is working for me. I try to make a project in visual studio 2015 (asp.net core). In given image I want to include header.html in index.html page. How can I do it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions but not for HTML, but other technologies like ASP.NET MVC or AngularJS.

You try this solutions for simple HTML.

http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp

Answer (score 0):

@Html.Partial("~/Views/CommonHtml/header.html")

Please see:
[What to use instead of WebViewPage.RenderPage method in ASP.NET 5 MVC6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29770041/what-to-use-instead-of-webviewpage-renderpage-method-in-asp-net-5-mvc6)

Answer (score 0):

In APS.NET MVC you have several options how to achieve this:

- using master page approach

  `@RenderBody() <!-- in master -->`

  `@{ Layout = "~/Views/Shared/master.cshtml" } <-- in child -->`
- Use partials

  `@Html.Partial("Partial")`

Here find more information about:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial

https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/views/creating-page-layouts-with-view-master-pages-cs